# smartphone application for ios and android

Tags: android, ios

I am begginer in developing mobile application and I want developing aplication what will be easily migrate from android to ios or back. I mean what can i do, if I want design aplication for two platformes.

Example: I will make application for android and my friend will change my application for ios. what methods or technologies is better for this style.

Comment: If OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't scare you off, I've had fun times porting my Android demo application for iOS. My interest lies on beefing up my knowledge on Objective-C though - not so much in applications themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/cross-platform-iphone-and-android-solutions/) will help you.

I have evaluated various cross-platform solutions, and all have certain disadvantages over native development, be it hardware access, availability of api, etc. Essentially, any cross-platform app development environment necessarily will adopt the lowest common denominator. Corona is great for games, if that's what you're after. Anything beyond that, and you're better off running two code streams.

Comment: Thx again i discovert on new thing: http://xamarin.com/ .. What about this?

Comment: Check out all the xamarin-related questions on here. You'll need to evaluate it based on your needs and your application's requirements.